# Consecutive days absent in row

Tags: excel, highlight

I'm currently trying to make a comprehensive attendance list to be used by my colleagues. One of the questions I got from one of them was, if it was possible to highlight a name of a person who has been absent 3 consecutive times on a given day.

So, the way my sheet has been set up is that in row 1:1 there’s the dates of the lessons. They are held on Tuesdays and Thursdays. On row 2:2 it gives the day, so it goes from tue, to thu, back to tue until the end of the year.

Column A:A contains the names of all the students the caveat is that, the students that follow the lessons on Tuesday are different than the ones on Thursday, so the cells with the absence will never be adjacent to one another.

Now is there a way, with conditional formatting or other, that I can highlight a students name, who has 3 consecutive A’s behind their name?

Comment: Can you clarify how you are showing absence or attendance?  For example - Are you highlighting the name or using another column that has Present or Not Present or 0 or 1 or whatever?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I gather from your post that you are marking absences with an "a" in the cell of the absent date, and each student will only be expected to attend on either Tuesdays or Thursdays, e.g. every other cell in the row.  I'm also assuming you'd want to continue highlighting for additional consecutive absences.  This is what I came up with, hopefully it works for you.
Highlight the range of cells you want to apply the conditional formatting to.

Conditional Formatting -> New Rule -> Use formula to determine which cells to format -> =AND(B3="a",XFD3="a",XFB3="a")

This worked for me as demonstrated in the below image.  Let me know if you need any adjustments and I'll see what I can do.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3p59.jpg)

Comment: Hey Chris,

i tried your way in a new sheet to replicate what you did, which works perfectly.

however in my sheet i have a few condtions i can toggle in columns C, D, E and F (just by marking them with an 'X') and some extra data in rows 3 and 4. So my formula would be: =AND(G5="a",XFD3="a",XFB3="a"), but this does not work. i guess because XFD is already the largest range, no?

Comment: Could you maybe put an image or example of what yours looks like so I can see specifically what you're working with?

Comment: Let's see if this works. http://imgur.com/CS9FqbN

This is the first part of the sheet, the rest is just filled in the same way.

Comment: I'm not 100% positive if this will work for you, as I'm not sure what all your values do for you, but see if =AND(C5="a",E5="a",G5="a") will work for you.  It seems to be working for me.

Comment: That worked, Chris! it seems way easier than the convoluted thinking i was doing. So thanks for doing the thinking i was unable to do.

Comment: No problem!  The first formula got weird by mistake when I changed the conditional formatting range, but still worked.  Cheers!